# Append javascript through controller action zf2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, zend-framework2

I have fixed HTML for email template in the database.

And I want to **redirect to some page** with form data on the **submit button** click from controller action.

In `$htmlOutput` I have the HTML. And I'm appending script like this,

```
$htmlOutput.='
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).find("#buttonSubmit").click(function () {
        console.log("clicked");
    });
});
</script>';
```

But it's not working. Where am I wrong?

Comment: so are you able to see this `console` statement in your browser console on click of submit button?

Comment: Nope. Nothing is happening. The script is showing with the HTML as a string. @vijayP

Answer (score 1):

Just add `echo` to add `$htmlOutput` value to DOM

```
echo $htmlOutput.="
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).find('#buttonSubmit').click(function () {
        console.log('clicked');
    });
});
</script>";
```

I assume you have `$htmlOutput="";` or something to concatenate.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But without `echo`, the script is available(showing) with HTML string content in the last. `echo` didn't worked for me. @Rishi

Comment: `<div></div><script type="text/javascript">
                            $(document).ready(function(){
                                $(document).find("#paypalpayment").click(function () {
                                    console.log("clicked");
                                    //$(document).find("#paypalform").submit();
                                });
                            });
                            </script>"` it's showing like this. in the console of inspect element. not working.

Comment: Try with just `$htmlOutput=` instead of `$htmlOutput.=` , I mean remove `.` dot

Comment: Now are you getting any progress ?

Comment: This is removing my existing HTML. and only script is there. Found another way to redirect. Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

For catch form submiting you need to use .submit method, not click.

```
$(document).find('#buttonSubmit').submit(function (e) {
 console.log('submited!');
 e.preventDefault();
});
```

P.S. And I'm not sure, you append script correctly in ZF2 context, it must be in form class, in form/element decorator, or in view .

Comment: Found another way to redirect. Thank you so much for your time.